# Netbeans IDE 8.2 cannot find file <iostream>

Tags: c++, netbeans, include, iostream

I downloaded Netbeans IDE to program in c++ and when I include the following code. The code is yet to be completed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;

Time::Time(){
    hour = minute = 0; 
}

void Time::setTime(int h, int m){
    hour =1;
}
```

I get a an error message in lines 1 and 3 saying

Cannot find include file .
Unable to resolve identifier std.

I've been searching around the internet and I can't seem to find a solution, all I've been told that "the libraries for c++ have yet been included in my folder". I've looked around the c++ options and it seems that there aren't any tools in "tool collection"

Comment: Netbeans is not really a good C++ IDE. But have you installed a C++ compiler?

Comment: What would be a good c++ ide? I was going to use visual studios, but its very confusing

Comment: Visual Studio is about a million times better C++ IDE than Netbeans. All IDEs are confusing when you start using them - you have to learn.

Comment: I would use visual Studios, but every time i run a program there is no output

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Ask a question about it (after searching here first - this is a very common problem).

Comment: Can you compile a simple Hello World program? If you can't your toolchain is broken.

Comment: NetBeans will not compile C++ programs "out of the box"; you must first install the C/C++ plugin and provide a C++ compiler. Those steps are simple, but essential. See [Configuring NetBeans IDE 8.0 for C/C++/Fortran](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html).